# python bignum array?

Tags: python

I'm very new to python.

I would like to have an array of exactly 10000 big integers (arbitrary precision).

I tried to do it like this:

```
M = []

M[0] = 1
M[1] = 1

for k in range(2,10001):
        M[k] = ...
```

but I get:

```
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

What data structure should I use and how do I initialize it and reserve space for it?

Comment: The answers below are correct, but it should be noted that it's not terribly common to do this. Just make the list when you need it, or when you have the data available that you actually want to put in it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The list isn't initialized correctly.

Try `M = [0]*10000`.  This will give you a list of the correct size.  Just replace the `0` with whatever default you want (or overwrite it with the right value afterwards).

Comment: Careful throwing the word `array` around here.  I would say "this will give you a *list* of the correct size".  I would also explain that in python an "array" is something (slightly) different and that the correct term is `list`.  (this can be helpful information to know when googling).

Answer (score 3):

Unlike JavaScript, you cannot assign array elements by index if they do not exist.  I suggest you simply append to the array:

```
M = []
for k in range(1,10001):
    M.append(k)
```

If the keys ARE important and you need to arbitrarially create them, use a `dict`:

```
M = {}
for k in range(1,10001):
    M[k] = ...
```

Comment: Your first example is better written as `M = [k for k in range(1,10001)]`  (or more simply:  `M = range(1,10001)` in python 2.x).  I only use the list comprehension because anytime you create a list using a for loop and append, you should ask yourself if a list comprehension would be appropriate.

Comment: @mgilson: I understand. Please feel free to append to my answer with these more in-depth methods.  I kept it super-simple because the OP was not very deep into python.

Answer (score 0):

To reserve the space:

```
M = [0] * 10000
```

then you can use:

M[0] = 1
M[1] = 1

for k in range(2,10001):
        M[k] = ...

Answer (score 0):

To work with big arrays you may consider using [Numpy](http://numpy.org/) as package for numrical computation and efficient storage and manipulation of large arrays. You could do something like this :

```
import numpy as np

M = np.arange(10000)
M[:2] = 1
```

To stay on the pure python side, I would do :

```
M = list(xrange(10000))
M[0] = 1
M[1] = 1
```

Timings using IPython (recommanded command line interpreter for playing with python) :

```
In [1]: %timeit M = list(range(10000))
10000 loops, best of 3: 195 us per loop

In [2]: %timeit M = list(xrange(10000))
10000 loops, best of 3: 190 us per loop

In [3]: %timeit M = np.arange(10000)
100000 loops, best of 3: 9.74 us per loop
```

Answer (score 0):

code

m=[ ];

m.append(1);

m.append(2);

m.append(3);

for k in range(2,1000):

```
    m.append(k);
```

print(m);

for object oriented this one will be good for append and delete 
adv: easy operation, easy usage , high flexibility.